# How does ER/Studio compare to VS2010 tooling?

Tags: .net, sql, visual-studio-2010

I'm new to the world of data and DBA work (I'm mostly an .NET developer)... we have an old version of ER Studio (7.5) and I'm wondering how it compares to what comes with VS 2010.

Your experience is much appreciated! Also, feel free to reccommend tags for this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found your question while searching for something else, but better late than never!

For anything other than trivial databases there's no comparison between the VS tools and ER/Studio.  I've been using ER Studio at various companies for eight years now (must speak to them about commission!) and can't envisage being without it.  In my field our databases have between 200 to 500 tables so really need proper tooling.

That said ER Studio has its faults, but its strengths, especially its scripting (including driving from .Net), far outweigh them.

Just a note of caution; if you're using SQL Server 2008 you'll need to check ER Studio 7.5 supports its new types. I can't recall which version first did this; but I do know 8.0 does.